# Access app.js function in adonisjs edge template

Tags: frontend, adonis.js

Can somebody explain to me how you access a function in the .edge template from the app.js file?

In `resources/js/app.js` I have

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log("works???")
}
```

In the edge template I have

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunc(); return false;">Some click</a>
```

And I get the error

```
VM6192 :19 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM6192 :19)
```

Note that I have the

```
<!-- Renders scripts -->
@entryPointScripts('app')
```

And the function is in the `http://localhost:8080/assets/app.js` path

I did manage to do something like `window.myFunc = myFunc`, inside app.js, but I need to call some async functions and I want the already compiled functions by webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do either:

1. map your function to window, in the app.js file (`window.myFunc = myFunc`), or
2. add an eventListener to the button you want
   `document.getElementById('my-btn').addEventListener('click', myFunc);`

In order to make es6 work, with features like async/await, you need to add babel;

1. install the babel polyfill: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#installation
2. install core-js: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#installation
3. create a `.babelrc` file with this configuration

   ```
   {
     "presets": [
       [
         "@babel/env",
         {
           "targets": {
              "edge": "17",
              "firefox": "60",
              "chrome": "67",
              "safari": "11.1"
           },
           "useBuiltIns": "usage",
           "corejs": "3.16"
         }
       ]
     ]
   }
   ```
4. run `node ace serve --watch` again